# Removing checkboxes from local storage with 'Unselect All' button

Tags: jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I'm trying to use "Unselect All" buttons to remove specific groups of checkboxes from local storage. In the Fiddle I have 2 groups of checkboxes.  I want each group to work independently of the other.  So if I select say, one country from each group (meaning there are now 2 id's in local storage), then if I click the 'Unselect' icon of one group, I want the country of the other group to STAY in local storage. At the moment everything is getting wiped out. All efforts failed so far.  Any ideas how I can get this working?  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s947vgoh/

```js
$(function() {

  // Saving checkboxes to local-storage
  var $containers = $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn, #CountryListBoxID_SECOND');

  $containers.on("change", "input", function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
    var selected = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    selected = '#' + selected.join(',#');
    localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', selected);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));
  });
});

// --------------
// TOP set of checkboxes

$("#CountrySelectAll_ID_prodn").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  var $containers = $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn');
  localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', '#' + $containers.find("input:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get().join(',#'))
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));
});

$("#CountrySelectNone_ID_prodn").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_prodn').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  localStorage.removeItem('#CountryListBoxID_prodn');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));
});


// --------------
// LOWER set of checkboxes

$("#CountryAll_ID_SECOND").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_SECOND').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  var $containers = $('#CountryListBoxID_SECOND');
  localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', '#' + $containers.find("input:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get().join(',#'))
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));
});

$("#CountryNone_ID_SECOND").on('click', function() {
  $('#CountryListBoxID_SECOND').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  localStorage.removeItem('#CountryListBoxID_SECOND');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<button type='submit' id="SelectALLCountryID_prodn">
           <i id="CountrySelectAll_ID_prodn" class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" title="Select All"></i>
</button>
<button type='submit' id="SelectNONECountryID_prodn">
           <i id="CountrySelectNone_ID_prodn" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" title="Unselect All"></i>
</button>
<hr>

<div id="CountryListBoxID_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN251" value="France" />France</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button type='submit' id="ALLCountryID_SECOND">
           <i id="CountryAll_ID_SECOND" class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" title="Select All"></i>
</button>
<button type='submit' id="NONECountryID_SECOND">
           <i id="CountryNone_ID_SECOND" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" title="Unselect All"></i>
</button>
<hr>

<div id="CountryListBoxID_SECOND">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="G80" value="Spain" />Spain</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="G500" value="Italy" />Italy</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox"  id="G300" value="UK" />UK</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you setting `selected_checkboxes` but removing something else.

Comment: I think I lost track with all my experimenting! But even when I remove selected_checkboxes it still wipes out everything (ie including any selections from the other group)

Comment: Please fix the setItem and getItem to access the actual items you need. You are setting a string and getting a string. When you remove Item you remove the string by the key given.

Comment: Believe me I hear you, and I now get each group on its own to work well.  But as soon as I click 'select all' of the other group it wipes out the first group's id's from local storage.  Obviously there's something I fundamentally don't get!

Comment: Does your fiddle work now? SO does not allow localStorage

Comment: Actually, things are worse.  Local storage works well for each group ON ITS OWN only.  But if I 'Select All' for one group, then 'Select All' for the other group, the second group enters local storage but wipes out the first group's id's.

Comment: All I want is for the each group to work on its own, completely unaffected by the other group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for click all/remove all, and single click - the code also sets the checked boxes onload from localStorage

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dso6jsnn/

The localStorage does not work at SO due to security settings

```js
var chks = {
  "CountryListBoxID_prodn": [],
  "CountryListBoxID_SECOND": []
}

function saveSet(id, checks) {
  chks[id] = checks;
  localStorage.setItem("selected_checkboxes", JSON.stringify(chks));
  console.log(id,localStorage.getItem("selected_checkboxes"));  
}

$(function() {

  var chks = localStorage.getItem("selected_checkboxes");
  if (chks) {
    chks = JSON.parse(chks);
    $.each(chks,function(key,val) {
      $.each(val,function(_,id) {
        $("#"+id).prop("checked",true);
      });  
    });
  }

  $(".sel, .remove").on("click", function() {
    var sel = $(this).is(".sel"),
      id = $(this).data("id"),
      $checks = $("#" + id).find(":checkbox");
    $checks.prop("checked", sel);
    saveSet(id, sel ? $checks.map(function() {
      return this.id
    }).get() : []); // save all or none
  });
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest("div");
    saveSet($container.attr("id"), $container.find(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
      return this.id
    }).get());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<button type='button' class="sel" data-id="CountryListBoxID_prodn">
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" title="Select All"></i>
</button>
<button type='button' class="remove" data-id="CountryListBoxID_prodn">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" title="Unselect All"></i>
</button>
<hr>

<div id="CountryListBoxID_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN251" value="France" />France</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<button type='button' class="sel" data-id="CountryListBoxID_SECOND">
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" title="Select All"></i>
</button>
<button type='button' class="remove" data-id="CountryListBoxID_SECOND">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" title="Unselect All"></i>
</button>
<hr>
<div id="CountryListBoxID_SECOND">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="G80" value="Spain" />Spain</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="G500" value="Italy" />Italy</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="G300" value="UK" />UK</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your time and help is much appreciated but I'm getting out of my depth here.  I've tried, but I don't really know how to use the code you've sent through.  Perhaps this isn't a straightforward question after all.

Comment: You're right.  This first part of the code allows the user to select any checkbox, and store that id.  The second part deals with the 'Select All/None'.  Both need to work, but because the first part of the code does already work then perhaps it's best to just remove it from the Fiddle and focus on the 'Select all/none' which doesn't work.

Comment: Many thanks for the fiddle and making my code 10 times more efficient.  I could be reading the console wrong (I'm used to seeing only the id's) but it appears that when both groups are selected - ie when 6 id's are in local storage - , if I try to 'Unselect' one of the groups it seems to wipe out everything instead of just the 3 id's from the group I'm unselecting.  Or is it me badly reading the console?

Comment: ... it seems to be happening for the individual checkboxes too, ie a selection in one group wipes out a selection in the other group.  Perhaps It's my fault that I wasn't clear but I'm looking for both groups to be independent of each other.  In other words, the setting of one group (or its individual countries) does not change because of the setting of the other groups.  It should be possible to have 6 id's in local storage.

Comment: I forgot a .get() - it works now http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dso6jsnn/ - I also added setting the checkboxes onload from localStorage.

Comment: @mrplungian it works!  All your efforts very much appreciated.  I'll certainly try to be much more concise in the way I ask a question next time.

Comment: No problem. If you need more direct help, my contact details are in my profile